# ListBox with Button in ItemTemplate should do Select on ButtonClick also

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a ListBox with an ItemTemplate.
In the ItemTemplate I have a Button and a TextBlock.

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxItemWithToggleButton.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Width="16" Height="16" Content="C" Padding="0" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

If I click the ListBoxItem on the TextBlock the ListItem is selected too,
but if I click on the Button the ListBoxItem is not selected.

How can I get both, the Buttonclick and the ListBoxItem selected every time I click the Button?

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing that using OnPreviewButtonClick:

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown"
                                 Handler="ItemOnPreviewMouseDown" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

and in the code behind:

```
private void ItemOnPreviewMouseDown(
            object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ListBoxItem) sender).IsSelected = !((ListBoxItem) sender).IsSelected;
        }
```

For the answers about this issue look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e988781-4ce9-4bf8-a09a-cb1e1b9158e5/select-listboxitem-via-button-in-datatemplate?forum=wpf).

Comment: But this only selects the ListBoxItem! Another click should deselect also. It's behavior should be exactly so like if the Textbox is clicked!

Comment: Hey, i edited the code. (the second part) according the requirement.

Comment: Yeah, but try it with SelectionMode="Extended" - it doesn't work as expected, cause your code toggles everytime.

Comment: i thought you wanted to toggle, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want the "normal" behavior if the ListBoxItem but also get the Button click. As you can read in the question, if I click the TextBox the behavior is ok, but if I click the button the selection isn't changing like "normal" (shift and ctrl select).

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to select the ListViewItem, you can get your dataobject from the DataContext of the Button and you don't need the data from other rows since you wanted a single selection anyway.

In the event-handler:
var data = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyData;

(On a side note, that being said, do you need selection at all? If not use an ItemsControl)

To make the ListViewItem select itself if the button is clicked you can use a ItemContainerStyle like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I want the ListBoxItem select for visual issues to the user (user reports error: "I clicked this, but it wasn't selected"). did you try your answer with multiselect - I can't get it work!

Comment: Did you change ListViewItem to ListBoxItem?

Comment: Yeah, sure I changed all ListView to ListBox.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll look into it. Give me some time.

Comment: can you reproduce it?